# Error running hive script in pseudo distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to run a hive script in pseudo distributed mode. The commands in the script runs absolutely fine when I run it interactive mode. However, when I add all those commands in a script and run I get an error.

The script:

```
  add jar /path/to/jar/file;
  create table flights(year int, month int,code string) row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde';
  load data inpath '/tmp/hive-user/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_2013_1.csv' overwrite into table flights;
```

The 'On_Time_On_Time_Performance_2013_1.csv' does exist in the HDFS. The error I get is:

```
   FAILED: SemanticException Line 3:17 Invalid path ''/tmp/hive-user/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_2013_1.csv'': No files matching path hdfs://localhost:54310/tmp/hive-user/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_2013_1.csv

  fs.default.name=hdfs://localhost:54310
```

My hadoop is running fine.

Can someone give any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but it is a more detailed and repeatable formulation of your question.

a) one needs to download the csv-serde from here:  git clone https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde

b) Build it using mvn package
c) Create a text file containing three comma separated fields corresponding to the three fields of the given table.
c) If the path is say "/shared" then the following is the correct sequence to load:

```
add jar /shared/csv-serde/target/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar;
drop table if exists flights;
create table flights(year int, month int,code string) row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde' stored as textfile;
load data inpath '/tmp/hive-user/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_2013_1.csv' overwrite into table flights;
```

I do see the same error as in the OP:  FAILED: SemanticException Line 2:17 Invalid path ''/tmp/hive-user/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_2013_1.csv'': No files matching path hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive-user/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_2013_1.csv